PHP MySQL Join 4 Tables limit results from 1 of the tables
I am having an issue joining 4 tables.  I can get all the tables to join but having an issue where when the 4 table joins it is returning multiple results but I only want to limit 1 to newest entry from the table.  Table 4 has multiple entries with the same uid but only need the la
$display = $db->select("
    SELECT tb1.*, tb2.*, tb3.*, tb4.* 
    FROM table_1 AS tb1 
    LEFT JOIN table_2 AS tb2 ON tb2.uid = tb1.uid 
    LEFT JOIN table_3 AS tb3 ON tb3.ply = tb2.pcn 
    LEFT JOIN table_4 AS tb4 ON tb4.uid = tb2.uid 
    WHERE tb3.flt = " . $postId . " 
");


Test 2 Should only be in there once with the 1.60 16.00 1.60 NOT the 0.00 29.90 2.90
EDIT:
I was able to get query to return just 1 result from table_4 but still not the newest entry from the table.
$display = $db->select("
    SELECT tb1.*, tb2.*, tb3.*, tb4.* 
    FROM table_1 AS tb1 
    LEFT JOIN table_2 AS tb2 ON tb2.uid = tb1.uid 
    LEFT JOIN table_3 AS tb3 ON tb3.ply = tb2.pcn 
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT tb4.* 
        FROM table_4 AS tb4 
        GROUP BY tb4.uid 
    ) AS tb4 ON tb4.uid = tb3.uid 
    WHERE tb3.flt = " . $postId . " 
");


" ... but I only want to limit 1 to newest entry ..."  So why don't you add the condition to get only the latest entry?

Where in the second query do you make any attempt to select the newest entry? You have no call to MAX(). Did you read and understand the linked question?

Also, how do you determine "newest"? I don't see any timestamps in your output.
